# Are there restrooms on trains in Israel?

Tags: trains, israel, hygiene

Many trains in Israel travel long distances.

I would like to know if there are restrooms on board all trains.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you attempt to book at [Rail Israel](http://www.rail.co.il) site you could see the amenities that a train has.

For example [Beer Sheva - Nahariyya](http://www.rail.co.il/EN/DrivePlan/Pages/DrivePlan.aspx?DrivePlanPage=true&OriginStationId=7320&DestStationId=1600&OriginStationName=Be%60er%20Sheva%20Center&DestStationName=Nahariyya&HoursDeparture=15&MinutesDeparture=0&HoursReturn=15&MinutesReturn=0&GoingHourDeparture=true&ArrivalHourDeparture=false&GoingHourReturn=true&ArrivalHourReturn=false&IsReturn=false&GoingTrainCln=2012-04-05&ReturnningTrainCln=2012-04-05&IsFullURL=true) for April 5th lists that trains have restroom in them.

P.S.  Not sure that I would consider trains in Israel travelling long distances.

Comment: Long is a relative term - for those living in Israel, 1.5 hours drive is really long. :)

Comment: An hour and a half without a bathroom can be a long time, depending on the person.

Answer (score 14):

Trains in Israel are hardly long distance. The longest is an hour and a half, two at a stretch. And yes, they have restrooms, but you can always go out at a station, and take the next train, if there's a real problem:-)

Your ticket is valid for a travel, once you pass the gate at the entrance of the origin station, till you exit at the gate of your destination station (where you surrender the ticket). In between you're free to step in and out the trains as you wish, as long as you don't exit the interim stations. Public restrooms are generally clean.

Answer (score 2):

All trains have restrooms.
Trains go from Naharia (north) to Beer Sheva (South)- which leaves the south of the country for bus use.
Almost no relevant trains for tourists in west-east direction, exept Jerusalem (which has nice view but take twice as long as a bus ride).